# Being one local directory for both GitHub and GitLab remote repos

Tags: git, repository

How do we have our one local directory for both GitHub and GitLab remote repos, always work as flawlessly as if each of two Git kind local repos is for each of the remote one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean to have two remotes synced with one local clone, just set up multiple remotes with `git` and you can optionally "group" them under the same name like `origin` or `all`.

It is explained very nicely [here](https://jigarius.com/blog/multiple-git-remote-repositories).

Since there are no name collisions I know of with special dirs like `.gitlab`, `.github`, `.gitlab-ci.yml` and such, any CI configs should be able to coexist without issue.